# React.js react-throttle with Meteor.js breaks in IE and Android Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

i'm writing a **Meteor** App (version 1.3.5.1) using **React**, version 15.2.0 and the module react-throttle (version 0.3.0).

When running on Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari (desktop and mobile) everything works fine. When running on **IE** or **Android Browser** (6.x), the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.handlersToWrap.includes is not a function
```

This is a line in the file:

```
/node_modules/react-throttle/lib/classes/processors/Base.js
```

**If i comment out that line, everything works like a charm on all browsers.**

To me it seems like `handlersToWrap` is an **array**. The method `includes` on arrays seems to be an **ES6 or ES7 method**, which is supported by Firefox,Opera etc. but not by IE and Android Browser (i tested that).

So now my question: How to fix that? Why does Meteor send an ES7-method to my client at all? Shouldn't it transpile first?

Of course i could replace `includes` with `indexOf` or something... but i don't want to mess around with React code that will be auto updated by npm...

Comment: You're right that you should not touch library code. What is your setup? Are you using webpack? babel? Do you have the setup for transpiling the code?

Comment: Ok, you gave me the right hint, it seems that Meteor is using its own transpiler package: [ecmascript](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/ecmascript) - this supports many ES2015 features - but `includes` seems to be an ES2016 feature (experimental). What would you suggest? Remove the module?

Comment: Babel is the defacto standard for transpiling, I'd go with that. I would find a nice boilerplate on github that has Meteor/React and whatever else you need, and than either adapt it to your needs, or use it as an example to set up your own project.

Comment: Sorry, mixed that up, the package `ecmascript` **is** the official Babel package for Meteor [see here](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation). It just does not support some ES7 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ES7 features like `include` are currently not supported by the Meteor babel package `ecmascript`. Others like spread/rest operators on objects are already implemented.

See the note [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), under Meteor and read the info.

I have removed the module that used that specific method call, as it was not vital to me. As there are few modules using features like this, i recommend doing the same if you run in this issue.